# Combine python fire with dataclass

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-dataclasses, python-fire

I have a code like below with multiple functions inside for various calculations.

I am using [python fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire) to pass arguments instead of defining argparse and call the functions from cli. Every time I add a new parameter I have to add `self` for it in init. I am looking for a better way.

I have found python [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) can be a way around it. I have looked into python fire [command grouping](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/guide.md#grouping-commands) and [multiple commands](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/guide.md#exposing-multiple-commands).

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(
        self,
        input_path: str,
        output_path: str = '',
        same_size: bool = False,
        crop_size: int = 300,
        padding: int = 20,
        write_json: bool = False,
        write_image: bool = False,
        line_thickness: int = 2,
        side_color: Tuple = (255, 255, 0),
        top_color: Tuple = (255, 0, 0),
    ) -> None:
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.input_path = input_path
        self.output_path = output_path
        self.same_size = same_size
        self.crop_size = crop_size
        self.padding = padding
        self.write_json = write_json
        ...
        ...

    def something(
        self,
    ) -> None:
        ...
        ...
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(MyClass)
```

**My question is how to get `MyDataClass` dataclass values in `MyClass` properly using python fire?**

```
@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    input_path: str
    output_path: str = ''
    same_size: bool = False
    crop_size: int = 300
    padding: int = 20
    write_json: bool = False
    write_image: bool = False
    line_thickness: int = 2
    side_color: Tuple = (255, 255, 0)
    top_color: Tuple = (255, 0, 0)
```

```
class MyClass:
    # init is not here anymore.

    def something(
        self,
    ) -> None:
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. Fire doesn't seem to generate a useful `--help` from a `@dataclass`

Comment: same goes for attrs-classes

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if fire supports it out of the box. Nevertheless, you can define a method in the runtime that summarizes all the dataclass attributes. That method can be fed to the `Fire`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from fire import Fire

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    input_path: str =''
    output_path: str = ''
    same_size: bool = False
    crop_size: int = 300
    padding: int = 20
    write_json: bool = False
    write_image: bool = False
    line_thickness: int = 2
    side_color: tuple = (255, 255, 0)
    top_color: tuple = (255, 0, 0)

    @classmethod
    def generate_init(cls):
        init_args = []
        for f in fields(cls):
            default = f.default
            if not default and issubclass(f.type, str):
                default = '""'
            init_args.append(f'{f.name}:{f.type.__name__}={default}')
        code = f'def fn(self, {", ".join(init_args)}):\n'
        code += '\n'.join(f'    self.{f.name} = {f.name}' for f in fields(cls))
        loc = {}
        exec(code, None, loc)
        fn = loc["fn"]
        cls.fire = fn
        return


MyDataClass.generate_init()
dc = MyDataClass()
Fire(dc.fire)  # use CLI
# Fire(dc.fire, "--crop_size=999")  # interactive example
print("Result:", dc)
```